# Automatically Move Cursor from One Textbox to Another

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a Web application that validates passkeys and displays some values there are four passkeys for a file to be entered Validate it, I am entering the passkeys just like we enter the Credit Card Number in the Payment gateway. In my present application I have enter one Passkey then have to press Tab or using the Mouse I have to select the Next Textbox to enter next Passkey, How do I Make the mouse Cursor to Jump automatically from one Textbox to Another Textbox after its maximum value filled like in Payment gateways

Comment: Please add javascript as a tag. Because this is mostly done in javascript so that post back is avoided.

Comment: @ Narendra Can U Suggest a Link where I can find the Javascript for this kind of event

Comment: There are enough answers added, you can refer them. These contains javascrupt events. You can check jQuery which is little easier. http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do pure javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidatePassKey(tb) {
  if (tb.TextLength >= 4)
    document.getElementById(tb.id + 1).focus();
  }
}
</script>

<input id="1" type="text" onchange="ValidatePassKey(this)" maxlength="4">
<input id="2" type="text" onchange="ValidatePassKey(this)" maxlength="4">
<input id="3" type="text" onchange="ValidatePassKey(this)" maxlength="4">
<input id="4" type="text" maxlength="4">
```

Comment: @ Rajeem If I have two textbox it will work I have Four what to do I have Write Separate JS for it?

Answer (score 1):

> In my present application I have enter one Passkey then **have to press Tab or using the Mouse** I have to select the Next Textbox to enter next Passkey

Don't do that. Just use the [`Control.Focus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) method.

When in HTML, you can use jQuery's [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/):

```
$("#textbox").focus();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with "don't do that". The automatic jumping behavior can be annoying and is not suitable for all cases. Users know how to switch to another textbox when they're ready, it doesn't have to be automatic.

Comment: @CodyGray I interpreted that sentence as OP using SendKeys and mouse move code to change focus in a Windows application. Automatic focus movement _can_ be useful, for example when entering license key or credit card information, i.e. a fixed format.

Comment: Ooohhh, well in that case, yes, completely agreed. That's a horrible idea. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's Onchange Event (or JQuery may be) on the Textbox which calls a method, where You can check the value of the Textbox if it equals the Maximum value , then setFocus on the next Textbox.

Comment: @ sohaiby Can U Suggest a Link where I can find the Javascript for this kind of event

Comment: @Rajesh Set an onChanged event on your textbox which calls a Javascript method.See how this works in this link
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use the TextBox.Focus() method on the next TextBox. 
Use the first TextBox's TextBox.TextChanged event to test if focus should be changed and to call the Focus method on the next TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a directive also to get the position move

```
<a href="https://plnkr.co/edit/G6sFMM9vaR6nQfVaMI2E?p=preview">directive 1</a>

<a href="https://plnkr.co/edit/G32KUITspNp1qsq6gleI?p=preview">directive 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#1").keyup(function(){
    var text_lenght = $('#1').val().length;
    if (text_lenght == 3) {
        $('#2').focus();
    }
});

$("#2").keyup(function(){
    var text_lenght = $('#2').val().length;
    if (text_lenght == 3) {
        $('#3').focus();
    }
});

});
</script>

<input id="1" type="text" class="form-control" name="phone1" maxlength="3" >
<input id="2" type="text" class="form-control" name="phone2" maxlength="3" >
<input id="3" type="text" class="form-control" name="phone3" maxlength="4">
```