# how to enable disable validators based on page controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, gridview

I have a gridView as follows.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvLocationCash" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="gridtable" DataKeyNames="LocationId">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Location Name" DataField="LocationName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" Visible="true"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAmount" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAmount" ErrorMessage="Please enter the Amount" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgvAmount" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAmount" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ErrorMessage="Please enter whole numbers only" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and a save button with the following code.

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnLocationAmountList" runat="server" OnClick="btnLocationAmountList_Click" Text="Save" Width ="100px" />
```

after the gridview is bound, there are about 20 rows in it.
When I type in numbers into the text box of the first row and press Enter key to go to second text box, the **Required Field Validator** is triggered for all the other 19 rows.

But, if I type numbers into the first text box and mouse click on the next text box, the RequiredFieldValidator is not triggered.

The page must be validated only if the **Save** button is clicked. Values must be entered for all the textboxes before save, and all the values must be integer only. (11,125,6589 etc). 
How to enable disable validators for a particular control?

**UPDATE:** here is the page_load event code in my class file.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindGrid();
            }
        }


        protected void BindGrid()
        {
            FinanceServiceRef.FinanceServiceClient obj = new FinanceServiceRef.FinanceServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IFinanceService");
            var ds = obj.ViewLocationAmountCashManagement();
            grvLocationCash.DataSource = ds;
            grvLocationCash.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: _"press Enter to go to second textbox"_ `Webforms != winforms`. If you press enter the page is submitted by default.

Comment: I'm afraid not @TimSchmelter . neither my page_load function isn't hit if it is a postback issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `onkeydown` in each text box in each `ItemTemplate`, like this:

onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);"

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" 
                     Visible="true"
                     onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode != 13);">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

> Note: The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key has a `keyCode` value of 13.

Comment: The validator event didn't fire. However it didn't go to the next textbox either. Is there any way to move on to the next textbox?

Comment: @Mahe - see accepted answer for [Automatically Move Cursor from One Textbox to Another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522431/automatically-move-cursor-from-one-textbox-to-another).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Validation Group property?

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvLocationCash" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="gridtable" DataKeyNames="LocationId">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Location Name" DataField="LocationName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" Visible="true"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAmount" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAmount" ErrorMessage="Please enter the Amount" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgvAmount" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAmount" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ErrorMessage="Please enter whole numbers only" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


<asp:Button ID="btnLocationAmountList" runat="server" OnClick="btnLocationAmountList_Click" Text="Save" Width ="100px" ValidationGroup="save" />
```

Comment: it doesn't work. hitting enter in the first textbox itself triggers page submit, which i don't want to happen. I need the enter key to perform a similar function of tab key (switching over to the next text box).

Comment: why you pressing enter to move to next textbox,you need to change the function of enter key press using jquery.