# How to automatically moving my cursor to div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'am trying to figure out, how to automatically moving my cursor to div? For example i clicked the green box then my cursor immediately moving to the white div.

[image]

i've trying to use jQuery `.focus();` but it seems doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically Move Cursor from One Textbox to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522431/automatically-move-cursor-from-one-textbox-to-another)

Comment: It's not possible - for a good reason.

Comment: Don't think you can move the actual cursor, but you can put focus on different elements.

Comment: 'focus' only works for a textbox not a div

Comment: I don't think there's a way to manipulate the cursor position for now and in the near future. Just imagine if lots of sites are violating this feature and the peasants cant move their cursor and blaming their mouse provider for a refund.

Comment: What if you move the entire page so the element is under the cursor instead of moving the cursor to the element?

Comment: @Wikiti not a good idea

Comment: Why are you writing a script to make people automatically transfer all their money to your account, every time someone logs into their online banking?

Comment: @Phill Healey No need to move the cursor to do that sir

Comment: @ReynaldHenryleo I know I'm just trying to point out a good example of why that sort of 'functionality' should never exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can't move your cursor with javascript. If its a focus-able element then you can transfer the focus to that element but can't move your cursor.

Comment: This should really be a comment not an answer.